# How to delete array of array if particular key doesn't exist in it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have collection of array and i want delete array of array where "answer_id" key is not exits.
my array look like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question_no] => 1
            [subject_id] => 1
            [question_id] => 255
            [currect_ans_id] => 2657
            [time_taken] => 110
            [is_visited] => 1
            [is_saved] => 0
            [answer_id] => 2659
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question_no] => 2
            [subject_id] => 1
            [question_id] => 256
            [currect_ans_id] => 2662
            [time_taken] => 0
            [is_visited] => 1
            [is_saved] => 0
        )


)
```

and want array like this(where answer_id key exits).

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [question_no] => 1
                [subject_id] => 1
                [question_id] => 255
                [currect_ans_id] => 2657
                [time_taken] => 110
                [is_visited] => 1
                [is_saved] => 0
                [answer_id] => 2659
            ) 
)
```

Comment: A simple for loop and unset?

Comment: i wants to delete without using loop

Comment: @VeerenderMishra No way of doing it without using a loop. All inbuilt functions also use a loop.

Comment: @vivek_23 problem has been solve.thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: You would normally be expected to make some effort in solving the problem rather than just asking others to solve it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter) to remove entries which don't have an `answer_id`:

```
$output = array_filter($input, function ($a) { return isset($a['answer_id']); });
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IMMUE)